# How to monitor switch in Nagios3?

Tags: networking, nagios, gnu

I need to monitor the traffic rate in my LAN. I have installed nagios core 3.2 and I can monitor services like CPU load, disk usage, http server, etc. but now, How to monitor traffic?

I am using GNU/Linux Debian Squeeze in all the machines of my LAN.

**EDIT:**

Switch: Cisco 1900 series

I have tried this [tutorial](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-routers.html) but it refers to files that does not exists in my system (eg. /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/switch.cfg), I think is because of version.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which plugins you have tried or looked at and what kind of router you are trying to monitor.

Comment: I wish I could answer your question directly, but after hours of frustration with Nagios, I installed Zenoss Core and never looked back.

Comment: I tried Zenoss core but I don't understand it. Some good tutorial for Zenoss core?

Answer (score 1):

Nagios - Monitoring Switches and Routers

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-routers.html

Comment: Thanks but that is really useless, that manual is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing I use MRTG to record and graph the traffic and Nagios to alert based on what MRTG reads. Check out Nagios plugins such as `check_rrd_bw`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want a tool like MRTG? That's made for this sort of thing. The only wa i can think of would be using an SNMP GET from Nagios, but I've never used it for that... most of my remote stuff has been through NRPE.

Comment: Have you used it? Do you think it will work?

Comment: I have used MRTG to monitor ingress/egress traffic on a cisco 3845 router with no issue. It produces nice graphs - you just have to make sure that you enable SNMP on the device you're trying to monitor (in case it isn't enabled by default). Check with the manufacturer for details.

Answer (score 0):

There are doezens and dozens of brand-specific SNMP plugins on http://exchange.nagios.org and http://www.monitoringexchange.org that will do this. On Nagios Exchange, for example, there are 37 plugins in the "Cisco" category.

You might also want to try the check_snmp_int plugin, here: http://nagios.manubulon.com/ I *think* it will work with switches, but you'd have to double-check to be sure.

Whether or not MRTG is a good answer to this question depends on what the asker means by "monitor"; MRTG will make nice graphs, and gather the data for you, but it does no alerting. Using check_mrtgtraf, you can have nagios "monitor" the MRTG data, this is a lot of work unless you already have MRTG set up.

Comment: I mean monitor LAN bandwidth. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've found a comfortable way to poll the data you're looking for, [PNP4Nagios](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/start) will give you a pretty good way to graph it automatically.